# Bash here document: redirecting the input vs typing it directly

Tags: bash, io-redirection, here-document

```
$ cat<<EOF
> a
> EOF
a
```

Can I automatically redirect the stream vs typing into stdin?  I have tried but this is what I get.

```
[debian:~]$ cat <<(printf "EOF\na\nEOF\n")
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
[debian:~]$ cat <(printf "EOF\na\nEOF\n")
EOF
a
EOF
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A here-doc is just one syntax for passing a particular input to the stdin of a program. But it's not the only one. You could also use:

- a pipe:

  ```
  printf "a\n" | cat
  ```
- a here-string:

  ```
  cat <<< "a"
  ```
- process substitution (as you already did):

  ```
  cat < <(printf "a\n")
  ```

(Note that the here-string will add a newline to the end of the given string. The others won't so I added one manually with `printf`.)

Passing the `EOF` strings to `cat` isn't probably very useful, it's just part of the here-doc syntax.